# Magento 2 select one color swatch and disable click?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

I want to disable click on magento 2 color swatch but they are not working if one color is here i use this code in swatch-renderer.js file but they are not working

```
      // Connect Tooltip
        container
            .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
            .SwatchRendererTooltip();

        // Hide all elements below more button
        $('.' + classes.moreButton).nextAll().hide();

        // Handle events like click or change
        $widget._EventListener();

        // Rewind options
        $widget._Rewind(container);

        //Emulate click on all swatches from Request
        $widget._EmulateSelected($.parseQuery());
        $widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());

        
        var swatchLength = $('.swatch-option.color').length; // if color attribute 
        if(swatchLength == 1){
           if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
   
             $('.swatch-option.color').first().click();
            $('.swatch-option.color').prop('disabled',true)
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable options after click first item:

```
jQuery('.swatch-option.color').first().click();
jQuery('.swatch-option.color').prop('disabled',true)
```

Comment: this code is working in console panel but not working in my swatch-renderer.js file.

Comment: you need to put after swatches was rendered

Comment: yes I added your code but code not working can you send me right place for this code

Comment: update your question to add where are you adding your code.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the day on this one, however this should have worked for you

```
 const parent = document.querySelector(".swatch-opt");
    parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const child = e.target.matches(".swatch-option, .swatch-option *");
        if (child) {
          event.preventDefault();
          child.prop('disabled',true);
        }
    }
    );
```